# How to install php depend on wamp?

Tags: php, windows, wamp

How to install php depend on project running in wamp on windows?
I've checked what's on website, but found nothing.
Thanks.

http://pdepend.org

Comment: What do you mean? The instructions are pretty clear in the documentation... http://pdepend.org/documentation/getting-started.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install PHP Depend on a WAMP installation follow these steps:

1. Download the latest phar-archive to a suitable location.
2. Check if the php executable is on your path. Start a command prompt and run: `where php`
3. If it returns a path, you can use `pdepend` by running `php pdepend.phar` (from a command prompt)
4. If it doesn't you must supply the full path to the php interpreter. The path to the php interpreter will be something like `\wamp\bin\php\{phpversion}\php.exe`, depending on your installation settings. The command will thus than be `\wamp\bin\php\{phpversion}\php.exe pdepend.phar`.
5. A second solution is modifying your `PATH` variable to include the php directory

Comment: Thanks! :D been banging my head for hours for this., by the way, which metric tools is best? I'm going to try php metric.,

Comment: @IrfandiD.Vendy [PhpMetrics](http://www.phpmetrics.org/) works simple and very well

Comment: so, I've tried phpdepend. It takes 40 minutes to generate a xml file which I can't understand (there is supposed to be 2 chart, but i forgot to add the argument), while phpmetrics could generate a neat chart with table of metrics in less than 5 minute.